# display session message only once during entire user session?

Tags: php, html, session

i have a html login form on my site that submits to login.php.
within login.php is a header redirect with a session message which echo's out onto the next page home.php.

what i am trying to do is make it so that this message only runs once and doesnt show again until the user logs in again. at the moment what is happening is the message is showing on each page refresh.

can someone please show me what i can do to sort this, thanks.

code in login.php:

```
<?php

    if (logged_in()) 
{ 
$_SESSION['login_message']="<div class=\"login-overlay\">
<h1>Login You In Securely</h1>
</div>"; 
header("Location:home.php");

}

?>
```

code in home.php:

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_message'] ))
   echo $_SESSION['login_message'];
    unset($_SESSION['loginframe2']) ;

?>
```

Comment: You are missing `session_start()` on your login.php

Comment: i have it in the top of my page but it still doesnt make a difference, the message still displays on each page refresh

Comment: Try this: unset($_SESSION['login_message']) ; instead of unset($_SESSION['loginframe2']) ;

Answer (score 1):

Simply `unset` the login message once it has been displayed.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_message'] )) {
    echo $_SESSION['login_message'];
    unset($_SESSION['login_message']);
}
```

Now if a user has seen the message, it won't be in the session anymore. And once he logs in again, login.php will set the variable again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use and track a variable like `$_SESSION['message_displayed']`.  Set it to true when you first display the message, and only display it if `!array_key_exists('message_displayed', $_SESSION)`